# Android calendar-like app that is simple enough to actually want to use

Tags: android, calendar

In 6 months of using Android, I am still to find a calendar or todo app which comes close to the simplicity and usability of the old Nokia/Symbian calendar that was, frankly, perfect. Is there anything at delivers that kind of crisp and uncluttered satisfaction? (That is: select date and time for reminder, type reminder text, optionally specify repeat period and/or duration, done)

Here are my criteria:

- I don't want to distinguish between "calendar" and "todo". It's a pointless distinction for me - some things in my life happen on specific days; some don't. I want to program reminders for any/all of them regardless of duration (often zero), repeat frequency (often 2 or 13 weeks), or similar.
- I want to be reminded of birthdays/anniversaries, tasks I need to remember ("buy milk"), appointments or other blocks of time when I'll be busy, and maybe nothing else.
- I want to be able to reschedule or be reminded at a future date/time easily after I choose to ignore a reminder
- I want to be able to repeat every n days/weeks/months/years and change n easily
- I don't want cloud connections. If it's offered, make it easily turned off and make it permanent. The cloud or my work PC doesn't need to know that I have to put the recycling out on the kerb - that's just cluttering my work life.

It may be really useful to be able to produce templates for the kinds of things I want to be reminded about (a template each for tasks, events, and anniversaries), and to hide all the seldom-used lower-value options (colour, sound) in the template set-up. When it comes to creating a reminder for event X or task Y, I want to be able type and tap as little as possible. Then my uncluttered organiser would turn out to be a template version of everyone's favourite organiser. Does such an organiser exist?

Comment: Not sure for 100% – but basically, *[Business Calendar Pro](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.appgenix.bizcal)* does that for me. I don't use tasks in there, though, so I cannot tell about that part – but moving entries is a breeze with simple drag-n-drop, for example, and reminders work reliably (incl. snooze-function). Be welcome to check [my calendar list](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/office_calendar_general) while waiting for real answers :)